# Log files for Excel macros when run with automation

Tags: vba, excel, automation

When an Excel macro, there are generally popups for what went wrong. Obviously this wont be the case if you're doing scheduled, automated runs with tools like Cruise Control or Bamboo. When an Excel macro fails, does it produce a log file somewhere? Are there other ways to determine what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to import a library for logging. It doesn't do it automatically.

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Log

Would be a good place to start. You'd have to write your own callback to log it somewhere else though.